# jQuery form upload error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins

I am using this version of jQuery form plugin https://raw.github.com/malsup/form/master/jquery.form.js
getting an error on submit:

error on line `form.submit();`

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. jquery.form.js, line 347 character 5
```

My code:

```
<form id="ajaxUploadForm" action="@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload a file</legend>
        <label>File to Upload: <input type="file" name="file" /></label>
        <input id="ajaxUploadButton" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </fieldset>
</form> 

$(function () {
        $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSubmit: function () {
               // $("#ajaxUploadForm").block({ message: '<img src="/Content/themes/start/images/progress.gif" />' });
            },
            success: function (result) {
               // $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                //$("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, result.message);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //$("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                //$("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file');
            }
        });
    });
```

I am doing this upload in side simple model dialog.

May be some one may have any ideas how ti fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller action that you are POSTing to is returning JSON you might need to wrap it in a `<textarea>` tags as explained in the documentation:

> Since it is not possible to upload
>   files using the browser's
>   XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin
>   uses a hidden iframe element to help
>   with the task. This is a common
>   technique, but it has inherent
>   limitations. The iframe element is
>   used as the target of the form's
>   submit operation which means that the
>   server response is written to the
>   iframe. This is fine if the response
>   type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work
>   as well if the response type is script
>   or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented
>   using entity references when found in
>   HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of
>   script and JSON responses, the Form
>   Plugin allows these responses to be
>   embedded in a textarea element and it
>   is recommended that you do so for
>   these response types when used in
>   conjuction with file uploads. Please
>   note, however, that if there is no
>   file input in the form then the
>   request uses normal XHR to submit the
>   form (not an iframe). This puts the
>   burden on your server code to know
>   when to use a textarea and when not
>   to. If you like, you can use the
>   iframe option of the plugin to force
>   it to always use an iframe mode and
>   then your server can always embed the
>   response in a textarea.

Comment: the problem is that Submit does not heppend, i put break point and check it under debug, it is not submitting, also looked in fiddler to make sure the request does not go somewhere else, no request there at all, it is just failing on submit for some reason. Mmm... by the way i have wrapped response in my controller

Comment: @Joper, hmm, that's weird. Have you tried doing this in a normal form (not one in some jquery dialogs)?

Comment: tried another browser (Mozilla latest) in Mozilla it is sending request(could see it in the fidder, but on debug i culdn't see that request coming on controller) but getting an error `ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request`. Before was trying Opera latest and IE latest

Comment: @Joper, how does your controller actions look like? Also how about testing this in a normal form without dialogs, directly in the main view?

Comment: thanks to fiddler, i see that it is doing post to the wrong url, POST /Home/Upload%%3E HTTP/1.1, have no idea from where %%3E coming, probably it just a piece of posted data?

Comment: @Joper, how does the `action` attribute of the form look like in the generated HTML?

Comment: my controller looking like in that sample http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

Comment: it is actually good question, so i am using razor view and sample where i was taking some code was written on WebForms, so i didnt take out %> from the end of action="@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")%>". Now of cause it is working when i took it out...