# JQuery Ajax Form with File Upload not working in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, file-upload, ajaxform

I'm using Jquery Ajax Form to upload files, which works well in Chrome and Firefox, but it doesnt work in IE. It pop ups a window telling me to save the file that I'm trying to upload.

Some example of my code, if necessary, is rite here:
HTML:

```
<div class="addNewDocumentContent">
<form id="AddNewDocForm" action="@Url.Action("AddNewDocument", "BidForm")" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div>
    <input name="File" type="file" style="width: 80%;" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        @Labels.Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" style="width: 80%;" />
</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">
    <button type="button" name="Back" value="Back">
       @Buttons.GoBack
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="Add" value="Back">
        @Buttons.Add
    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
//Document Ready=============================================================================
$(function () { 

    $('#AddNewDocForm').ajaxForm({
        type: 'POST',
        beforeSubmit: function () {
            return $("#AddNewDocForm").valid();
        },
        success: function (documents) {
            FillDocuments(documents);
            $('#dialogAddNewDocument').dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
//Validate====================================================================================
//Validation=====================================================================================
$(function () {
    $("#AddNewDocForm").validate({
        ignore: ":not(:visible)",
        rules: {
            File: "required",
            Name: "required"
        }
    });
});
//=========================================================================================
```

Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddNewDocument(DocumentModel document)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<DocumentModel> documents = null;
            if (Session["Documents"] != null)
            {
                documents = (List<DocumentModel>)Session["Documents"];
                var doc = documents.OrderByDescending(x => x.Number).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

                document.Number = doc != null ? doc.Number + 1 : 1;
                document.FileName = document.File != null ? document.File.FileName : document.FileName;
                documents.Add(document);
            }
            else
            {
                documents = new List<DocumentModel>();
                document.Number = 1;
                document.FileName = document.File != null ? document.File.FileName : document.FileName;
                documents.Add(document);
                Session["Documents"] = documents;
            }

            var displaydocs = documents.Select(x => new
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Number = x.Number,
                File = x.File != null ? x.File.FileName : x.FileName,
                Route = x.Route != null ? x.Route : "#",
            });

            return Json(displaydocs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and finally model:

```
  public class DocumentModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
}
```

Again, it works in every browser except IE8. Im probably not the only one, but I havent found an answer out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried with a textarea yet, but it works fine if I define the content type to return inside the action as text/html:

```
 return new JsonResult() { ContentType = "text/html", Data = result };
```

Answer (score 4):

This question [has been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635927/jquery-form-upload-error) asked [many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417977/how-do-i-prevent-ie-save-file-dialog-when-using-fileupload-in-asp-net-mvc). Please search before posting. The [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) states it clearly:

> Browsers that support the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 will be able to
>   upload files seamlessly and even get progress updates as the upload
>   proceeds. For older browsers, a fallback technology is used which
>   involves iframes since it is not possible to upload files using the
>   level 1 implmenentation of the XMLHttpRequest object. This is a common
>   fallback technique, but it has inherent limitations. The iframe
>   element is used as the target of the form's submit operation which
>   means that the server response is written to the iframe. This is fine
>   if the response type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work as well if the
>   response type is script or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented using entity references when
>   found in HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of script and JSON responses when using
>   the iframe mode, the Form Plugin allows these responses to be embedded
>   in a textarea element and it is recommended that you do so for these
>   response types when used in conjuction with file uploads and older
>   browsers. Please note, however, that if there is no file input in the
>   form then the request uses normal XHR to submit the form (not an
>   iframe). This puts the burden on your server code to know when to use
>   a textarea and when not to.

Since you are returning JSON from your controller action you need to respect what the documentation says => wrap in a `<textarea>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  cache:'false' inside your AJAX call...
Something like:

```
 $.ajax({
 type:"POST", 
 url:'process.php',
 cache:'false',   //IE FIX
 data: data, 
 success: function(){ //on success do something...

 } 
 });
```