# jQuery form not working on internet explorer

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, grails, file-upload

I am using jQuery form to upload files and save them into database, my code works fine in chrome and mozilla but the upload doesn't start in internet explorer; I am grails framework and my codes are as follows :

```
<g:form controller="uploadImage" action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imageUploaderForm" id="imageUploaderForm">
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="submitImageUploaderForm()" />
    <g:hiddenField name="imageType" value=""/>
</g:form>

$("#imageUploaderForm").ajaxForm({
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({
            value : percentComplete
        });
        $(".progress-label").html(percentComplete+" %");
    },
    complete: function(response){
        //something
    }
});

function submitImageUploaderForm(){
    //This method gets called !
    $("#imageUploaderForm").submit();
}
```

And in the controller i have the following

```
def uploadImage = {
    def response = [result:false,message:"Image could not be uploaded.",uploadInstanceId:0]
    def uploadImage = new UploadImage(params)
    if(uploadImage.save()) response = [result:true,message: "Image uploaded sucessfully.",uploadInstanceId:uploadImage.id]
    render response as JSON
}
```

Nothing happens in the page when I try to upload a file but after a while a get the following exception:

```
Message: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Read timed out
```

Comment: Are you trying to upload the file with Ajax? If so, this will not work. Research the subject.

Comment: yes, i am trying to upload the file using AJAX. This code works fine in mozilla and firefox but not in internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, uploading files via Ajax just won't work in IE. See the jQuery docs on file upload. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

This question has, as James points out, been asked before, and it isn't specific to Grails.
[JQuery Ajax Form with File Upload not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233610/jquery-ajax-form-with-file-upload-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

I used hidden iFrame to upload file while in internet explorer, while in other browsers, the the file is uploaded using AJAX using the code shown above.